# Find index of string in an array of strings where overlap could occur

Tags: java, string, algorithm, full-text-search, text-search

I am having some trouble writing a variant of sub-string search. Essentially the goal is to write a method that can perform sub-string search except that the source data is in an array of Strings rather the one String.

I have looked around and can't find anyone who has managed to solve this elegantly.

Consider some input data such as:

```
final List<String> source = new ArrayList<String>();
source.add("abc");
source.add("def");
source.add("ghi");
source.add("jkl");
source.add("mnop");
```

Now let's say I want to write a method that can return a Pair of the first location of where the target String appears. This Pair represents the first index of the String in the source array where the target appears and its index within that String where the target starts.

Examples with 0 based indices:

```
subStringArray(source, "def"); //returns Pair(1,0) - 2nd string - 1st index
subStringArray(source, "ef"); //returns Pair(1,1) - 2nd string - 2nd index
subStringArray(source, "fgh"); //returns Pair(1,2) - 2nd string - 3rd index
subStringArray(source, "hijklmno"); //returns Pair(2, 1) - 3rd string - 2nd index
subStringArray(source, "abcf"); //returns null or Pair(-1,-1);
```

I know it would involve three for loops but I'm not sure how to handle the edge cases, i.e where the target String takes up multiple Strings in the source array.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I started cobbling some stuff together, but as I said, the edge cases make it difficult to reason about.

Comment: Why not joint all source data and label every char with the `Pair` you need

Answer (score 0):

Pls see this

[Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm), a string searching algorithm, with linear complexity to solve this problem.

Comment: I think this is the inverse of what I am looking for. I need to find the first occurrence of my target string in the dictionary rather then finding occurrences of the dictionary in my target string.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to concatenate all the Strings and maintain their lengths.

```
ArrayList<Integer> lens = new ArrayList();
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for(Stirng str : list){
 s.append(str);
 lens.add(str.length()); 
}
int index = s.indexOf(target);
if(index == -1)
 return "-1";
else
{
  int  i = 0;
  while(index - lens.get(i) > 0)
  {
    index -= lens.get(i);
    i ++;
  }
  return i + " " + index;
}
```